# Data level on Bar chart

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a Sentiment Analysis project and I want to add data levels on my bar chart, could anyone please help me with it. Thanks in advance. :)

```
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
data['Months'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(11, 6), rot=0)
plt.xlabel("Months", labelpad=16)
plt.ylabel("Count of Ratings", labelpad=12)
plt.title("Company - Count of Ratings by Months", y=1.02);
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously, you forgot to upload your image. I suppose, your intention will be specified there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. please see below image link as I am unable to upload the image. 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_iOGAEyTZov7YcF6YscsFSlvHilSnRaO

Comment: Just considered to upload the image itself. It helps the answerer working on your question.

Comment: Just did, please look at the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out the answer. :)

```
dx = data['Days'].value_counts()
dx.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(14, 7), rot=0, color='blue')

for i, v in enumerate(dx):
    plt.text(i -0.15, v +.2, " "+str(v), fontweight='bold')
```

Comment: you could "accept" your own answer, By that, others know, your question has been answered (in this case by yourself).